# Media query not works on chrome emulator but not on actual screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a weird issue.

I created a media query for screen height 768px. When I open chrome dev tools -> emulator and set the resolution to 1366 X 768 it works as expected.

When I close the dev tools I can see the media query css didn't apply.

I opened the console and checked: screen.height, screen.width, screen.availHeight and screen.availWidth.

Both heights returned 768, both width returned 1366.

What can be the issue?

The media query is as follows:

```
@media screen and (height: 768px)
```

Comment: How are you sure the CSS didn't apply if you closed the dev tools?  Could you perhaps post the exact query?

Comment: Would help if you list your media query. Possible that the media query you are using is applied to `devices` only.

Comment: added to the original post

Comment: @GalZiv can you check the result with `mediaMatch` that I specified below?

Comment: sorry for the delay. i wanted to attach a screen with the specified resolution. now that i cannot find, i change the resolution on my screen to 1360 X 768

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the query you are using does't matching with the corresponding device/media you are testing.

To check whether your query applies you can check with the [`mediaMatch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) api:

Assuming you're query was something like this:

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768)").matches
```

This returns a `boolean`. You can check what `mediaMatch` returns for your specific usecase.

Comment: your query is against the width, i need height 768. anywyas this is the queries i ran: window.matchMedia("(min-height: 768)").matches; window.matchMedia("(height: 768)").matches; both returned false. why is that?

Comment: using the function you mentioned i've noticed that when I use (max-height: 768px) returns true while (height: 768px) returns false. how could it be considering screen.availHeight\height returns 768? and of course thank you for your answer

Comment: @GalZiv You should be using [`window.innerWidrth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) to get the actual width of the viewport. When you use `screen` you are referring to the actual monitor size and not the browser/viewport size. The query you listed is working properly.